# Is there a way to use a single "foreach" for all three "preg_match" at the same time in my case?

Tags: php

Bonjour.

I have three `preg_match`

```
preg_match($keyword_in_start_title,$line) 
preg_match($keyword_with_space,$line)&&!(preg_match($keyword_in_start_title,$line)) 
preg_match($keyword,$line)&&!(preg_match($keyword_with_space,$line))&&!(preg_match($keyword_in_start_title,$line))
```

and I would like to use them all at once since all three are placed in the same:

```
foreach(preg_split("/((\r?\n)|(\r\n?))/",$txt) as $line){
    ...
}


$txt = file_get_contents("database.txt");

$keyword = "/" . $search_keyword . "/i";
$keyword_with_space = "/" . " " . $search_keyword . " " . "/i";
$keyword_in_start_title = "/" . "<b>" . $search_keyword . "" . "/i";

foreach(preg_split("/((\r?\n)|(\r\n?))/",$txt) as $line){
    if(preg_match($keyword_in_start_title,$line)){
        if(!($search_keyword=="")){
            echo "<div class='item'>";
            $line = highlight($line,$search_keyword);
            echo $line;
            echo "</div>";
        }
    }
}

foreach(preg_split("/((\r?\n)|(\r\n?))/",$txt) as $line){
    if(preg_match($keyword_with_space,$line)&&!(preg_match($keyword_in_start_title,$line))){
        if(!($search_keyword=="")){
            echo "<div class='item'>";
            $line = highlight($line,$search_keyword);
            echo $line;
            echo "</div>";
        }
    }
}

foreach(preg_split("/((\r?\n)|(\r\n?))/",$txt) as $line){
    if(preg_match($keyword,$line)&&!(preg_match($keyword_with_space,$line))&&!(preg_match($keyword_in_start_title,$line))){
        if(!($search_keyword=="")){
            echo "<div class='item'>";
            $line = highlight($line,$search_keyword);
            echo $line;
            echo "</div>";
        }
    }
}
```

So, is there a way to use a single `foreach` for all three `preg_match` at the same time ???

If yes, how to proceed please ???

Thank you for answering me.

Comment: Just use || conditions for preg_matches.. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are printing the line when it matches all your 3 keywords. Use `||` instead of multiple conditions with `&&`

```
foreach(preg_split("/((\r?\n)|(\r\n?))/",$txt) as $line){
    if(preg_match($keyword,$line)|| preg_match($keyword_with_space,$line) || preg_match($keyword_in_start_title,$line)){
        if(!($search_keyword=="")){
            echo "<div class='item'>";
            $line = highlight($line,$search_keyword);
            echo $line;
            echo "</div>";
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps..